# Group by location and group in template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I try to display data from db and place them under correct title.

models.py

```
class Game(models.Model):
    location= models.ForeignKey('location', on_delete=models.CASCADE')
    group = models.IntegerField()        
    firstname = models.CharField()
    surname = models.CharField()
```

views.py

```
class group(generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'group.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        game = Game.objects.filter(location__type__pk=kwargs['pk']).order_by('location__pk', 'group')            
        context = {
            'game': game,
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Lets say that the 'group' can be like A, B, C etc.

In the template I want to display it like

```
Location Foo
  Group A
    Jonas Andersson
    Lisa Silverspoon
  Group B
    Sven Bohlin
    Göran Lantz

Location Bar
  Group A
    Mia Milakovic
    Lars Larsson
  Group B
    Anna Annasdotter
```

I have tried with so many variants of for-loops without any success.

Is it possible? Can you do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use template filter [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup), as in,

```
{% regroup games by location as games_list %}

{% for location, games in country_list %}
    {{ location }}
    {% for game in games %}
       {{ game.group }}
       ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note: games here is a list, which is why you need to loop over it again.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The builtin [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) tag should enable you to do this, but you'll need to use it twice in order to achieve the nested grouping that you're looking for.

```
{% regroup game by location as games_loc %}  <!-- Group by "location" -->
{% for location, l_games in games_loc %}
    <div>{{ location }}</div>

    {% regroup l_games by group as games_grp %}  <!-- Group by "group" -->
    {% for group, g_games in games_grp %}
        <div>{{ group }}</div>

        {% for g in g_games %}  <!-- Display games in group -->
            <div>{{ g }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @devbob - did this give you the desired result?